# CSS Grid push rows to top based off content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the below example is it possible to have the grid item's height be based off content and pushed to the top? I tried setting some `grid-template-rows` and `grid-auto-flow` but that doesn't seem to work either.

So it would look like this:
[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.wrapper > li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Heading</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What you're asking about is a masonry layout. Here's how it works in grid css: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Ah I see, thanks for that link. I wanted to avoid using JS if possible but it looks like this isn't possible with just CSS then if the height is undefined.